# OneNote API: "Query operation not accepted" when filtering a pages GET

Tags: onenote-api

I'm attempting to get a list of pages by notebook from the OneNote REST API.

One option is to iterate over a list of sections and GET pages per section using  `/api/v1.0/notes/sections/[ID]/pages`

Instead, to reduce the number of requests I'm filtering a call to `/v1.0/me/notes/pages` by `parentNotebook/id` but I'm getting, for example:

```
The query operation(s) parentNotebook/id eq [ID] 
OR parentNotebook/id eq [ID] OR parentNotebook/id eq [ID] not supported.
http://aka.ms/onenote-errors#C20106
```

Error #20106 states:

> Your request contains a query operator that is not supported. See
>   OneNote API reference.

My brief reference to the OData 4.0 docs leads me to believe that `parentNotebook/id` is the correct syntax, so what am I doing wrong please?

**UPDATE**

So, it does work, if I do one at a time; the problem seems to be the `OR`?

Can I change my filter to include multiple notebooks or should I be doing an API call per notebook?

Ironically when I did do a call per notebook I got my first http 429 throttling hand slap, though adding a 2 second pause between requests seemed to solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried the following in the [interactive console](http://dev.onenote.com/docs#/reference/get-pages/get?console=1) and got back a successful 200 response.

```
GET https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages?filter=parentNotebook/id eq '0-C6703B3BE9D6A5E0!317' or parentNotebook/id eq '0-D8E91FC12048CF4A!515'

 *NOTE* replace the above notebook ids with your own ids.
```

So filtering on multiple notebooks using or expression is possible.

Comment: You're right. I had a syntax error in my URL.I didn't have quotes around the page ID